# how do I use multiple data rows as a single input in TFLearn?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

I'm attempting to use TFLearn (or TensorFlow directly) to reconstruct a noisy (as in harmonics) signal. My input has 168 columns to be converted to 84 outputs. I want to treat each column pair as a single pixel. I don't have to go realtime, so I want to use multiple rows of the input to generate a single output. I guess that I need at least 20 rows of input (10 on either side) to compute a single row of output. How do I reshape my data appropriately? E.g. see comments:

```
def learn1(data, answers): 
    # data.shape == 5000x168, answers.shape = 5003x84
    network = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 20, 84, 2])
    ... set up 2D convolutional network ...
    model = tflearn.DNN(network)

    X = # data reshaped into overlapping groups of 20 -- what goes here?
    Y = # I don't have any labels. What goes here?
    Y_test = # what goes here?
    model.fit(X, Y, n_epoch=50, shuffle=False, 
        validation_set=(answers, Y_test), batch_size=10)
```

I can generate test data at will. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why is the answers array so large? If the answers are the expected output of the network for the data (which they should be) they must have the shape of 250x84

Comment: Each answer is 1x84. And those 84 are booleans -- simple on/off values.